# Is there a computer science equivalent page for this: "How to become a GOOD Theoretical Physicist"?

Tags: advice-request

http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gadda001/goodtheorist/

I was wondering if any one has come across a page similar to the above but for CS.

Comment: you might be interested in Tao's career advice for mathematicians: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/

Comment: Yeah, that's the sort of thing I was looking for but with a more computer science-y spin.

Comment: This is the closest thing I've found so far:  http://matt.might.net/articles/what-cs-majors-should-know/